# How to extract delimited entries that match criteria?

Tags: text-processing, grep, agrep

I have a log file where each entry is delimited by a series of `---`, similar to this:

```
-----------------
Name=Operation1
Time: 100
Status=Success
-----------------
Name=Operation1
Time: 500
Status=Failure
-----------------
Name=Operation2
Time: 200
Status=Success
-----------------
Name=Operation2
Time: 800
Status=Failure
-----------------
```

I would like to extract all of the entries matching certain criteria (i.e. all entries where `Name=Operation1` or all entries where `Status=Failure`). I thought I could use agrep as follows: `agrep -d "---*" -e "Name=Operation1" mylogfile > myfilteredlogfile` but after inspecting the file it doesn't seem to filter as I expected. What's wrong with my filtering and how can I extract my desired entries?

Answer (score 0):

If your `awk` allows for multibyte record separators, try

```
awk -vRS="-----------------" -vORS="-----------------" '/Failure/' file

Name=Operation1
Time: 500
Status=Failure
-----------------
Name=Operation2
Time: 800
Status=Failure
-----------------
```

Answer (score 0):

How about some perl:

```
perl -0777 -snE 'say join "---", grep {/$patt/i} split /^-+$/m' -- -patt="status=fail" file
```

```
Name=Operation1
Time: 500
Status=Failure
---
Name=Operation2
Time: 800
Status=Failure
```

That slurps the file in as a single string, splits it into records, finds the matches, and then joins it with an approximation of the record separator.